# How to host a html website on a QNAP NAS Server

Tags: html, qnap

I would like to know how to host a simple html website on a QNAP NAS sever. All of the tutorials I have found are extremely vague and do not work at all. Thank you!

I already have a domain name ready for the website.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you how to do this since I also tried and failed to find good explanation, leading me to this post. But I can tell you that I read several places that say that this is a BAD IDEA. [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/qnap/comments/dgmowi/tutorial_how_to_connect_your_qnap_safely_from_the/)

Answer (score 1):

Its too simple . Just go to your qnap admin address

Control panel -> Web Server

Then enable it and specify desire port (be careful to use an available port)

Click apply then go to file station.
A new shared folder is created under name of Web.

Copy your html file in it and name it index.html

you should see your website on your ip:desired port .

if you get error you should fix index.html file permissions on file station .

I have a simple html page on my nas like this

you can also host multiple websites on your nas using Control panel -> Web Server -> Virtual host.

create a virtual host for every website you want to host . assign a folder (or creat one) to it and specify a port.
It has almost no options for hosting like nginx but it can WORK!

I also use Nginx in docker to achieve more options on my websites on nas .You can install nginx using Entware too (without docker and container station).